# Mouse events in svg workaround for microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, html, svg, microsoft-edge

I am loading an SVG file in an `<object>` tag of a html page. The SVG contains images with mouse events `onclick`, `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`. I find that those trigger as they should in firefox and google-chrome.

When I load the page with Microsoft edge I find that:

- `onclick` does not seem to trigger,
- `onmouseover` trigers many times when I move the mouse over the image (and not only once),
- `onmouseout` does not seem to do anything either.

Googeling the issue reveals that I am not the only one who encounters the problem with Microsoft edge and that the issue is older.

But are there any workarounds for this sort of problem?

Comment: Don't load the SVG into an `<object>` element. Just put it on the page.

Comment: Ok, there was a reason though not to have it inline: The svg is large and it is inside of `<li>` and some `<div>`'s. I need to enlarge it with css to fit its height to the screen height and be able to change its horizontal position. In other browsers I got this working only that way. Perhaps I can try your proposal as a browser specific solution if that works in edge. However, it implies a lot of changes on the javascript side. Maybe there is another tag that I can try to replace the `<object>` with?

Comment: Not really. For SVGs to be interactable, they need to be apart of the DOM.

Comment: Well, I see the svg content in the DOM inspector of firefox and chrome ...

Comment: I made some experiments and found that the `<object>` tag is not the crucial or at least not the only problem. I load the svg now in a `<div>` tag. This way, the mouse events are still not ok in edge.

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: @highsciguy Did you find any workaround? I'm also facing the same issue (specific to Microsoft Edge browser)?

Comment: @highsciguy Did you ever find a way to fix this?

Comment: No other workaround than the obvious one of avoiding IE for not being conformant to anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found that for the svg sub-elements in which I set css to `{pointer-events: bounding-box}` that `bounding-box` was not a css option in Edge.  I changed css for these elements to
`{pointer-events: visible}` for Edge and then my mouse events fired as they did in Chrome and Firefox.